How to call functions with Discord.py?
Calling functions like normal gives me an error.
:(
Every time I try to do  await warn(ctx, member) it gives me an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
@bot.hybrid_command()
async def warn(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"Please, {member.name} do not send any form of bad words, Thank you!", ephemeral=True)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message): #checking/reading the messages
    guild = bot.get_guild(SEVER_ID)
    channel2 = bot.get_channel(GENERAL_CHANNEL)
    

    if guild is None:
        print("No Guild")
        return
        
    channel = guild.get_channel(REPORT_CHANNEL)

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    result = profanity.contains_profanity(message.content)

    if result == True:   #deciding if they are bad and adding a report
        badword = True
        await channel.send("**Message: **" + message.content + " | " + "**User: **" + message.author.name)
        await channel.send("<@&1284787770874658939>")
        member = guild.get_member(message.author.id)
        await warn(ctx, member)
        await message.delete()

        await bot.process_commands(message)

it gives me an error with the "warn" command and "on_message" event
can anyone help?
anything would be appreciated!

It seems that guild.get_member() returns a string, and a string has no attribute name. Maybe take a look at this thread, where the problem eventually seemed to be that it required the Guild.members intent

i have the members intent enabled.

Can you give me the result of print(member)?

hogan5780 is the result

If it's returning hogan5780 (a string) then I don't know where it's going wrong. guild.get_member() should return guild.Member or None

personally i think its where im calling the function

or could be the guild.

When you use the @bot.hybrid_command() decorator, you're converting your warn() function into a command, which implies changes to the invocation parameters that I haven't looked into. But in any case, if you need to call your warn() function in other parts of the code, I recommend that you isolate it from the warn command. For example:
async def warn(msg: discord.Message):
    await msg.reply(f"Please, {msg.author.name} do not send any form of bad words, Thank you!", delete_after=5)

@bot.hybrid_command(name="warn")
async def warn_cmd(ctx: commands.Context, message: discord.Message):
    await warn(message)
    await ctx.reply(f"Message {message.jump_url} warned.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message): #checking/reading the messages
    guild = bot.get_guild(SEVER_ID)
    channel2 = bot.get_channel(GENERAL_CHANNEL)
    

    if guild is None:
        print("No Guild")
        return
        
    channel = guild.get_channel(REPORT_CHANNEL)

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    result = profanity.contains_profanity(message.content)

    if result == True:   #deciding if they are bad and adding a report
        badword = True
        await channel.send("**Message: **" + message.content + " | " + "**User: **" + message.author.name)
        await warn(message)

        await bot.process_commands(message)


now it gives me 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'interaction''

Now that I've paid attention to your code, where are you getting the ctx parameter in the on_message event?

its defo something to do with the member parameter

If you want your warn function to also be triggered by messages (in which you are not given an ctx or interaction parameter), you will have to adapt it to work based on channels only. I've made this adaptation in the code to explain.

tbh idk, i got it from other peoples code

I do have a global variable for ctx, 'ctx = commands.Context'

ctx cannot be a global variable, since it is related individually to each command triggered. You need to adopt a solution based on messages only, as I've shown in the code above. To trigger the warn command, you need to enter a message ID or Link

Thx, it worked! :D
